# Split large array formula to use in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to split months into weekly dates, while doing that if any particular start date of week matches with Holidays it should move to next working day. Final corrected date are given in highlighted column.

(Cant post the image or excel sheet since it doesn't allow me for being newbie)

With some help I have figured out the array formula to do this, but that is very long and cant use it in VBA due to 255 character limit

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$M$2:$M$14,0)),MIN(IF((MMULT(--
  (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))
  =TRANSPOSE($M$2:$M$14)),ROW($M$2:$M$14)^0)=0)*
  (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31))))>C2,
  (MMULT(--
  (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))
  =TRANSPOSE($M$2:$M$14)),ROW($M$2:$M$14)^0)=0)*
  (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))))),C2)
```

I need to break this into smaller version or in parts so that I can use it in VBA.
Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what 255 limit are you referring to? and what you ware doing with that string?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 255 character string limit you can declare the variable and concatenate to it like so:

```
Dim strFormula As String

strFormula = "IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$M$2:$M$14,0)),MIN(IF((MMULT(--
    (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))
    =TRANSPOSE($M$2:$M$14)),ROW($M$2:$M$14)^0)=0)*
    (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31))))>C2,"

strFormula = strFormula & "(MMULT(--
    (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))
    =TRANSPOSE($M$2:$M$14)),ROW($M$2:$M$14)^0)=0)*
    (ROW(INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),1,1)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(YEAR(C2),12,31)))))),C2)"
```

Comment: I tried using it but its giving me some parenthesis(end statement required) error. I tried matching up all the parenthesis looks ok to me.